# Как правильно обойти список дат, добавленных в List

Tags: java, дата, list, коллекции, arraylist

После добавления в List - я хочу обойти эти даты в цикле, но на экран выводится только одна дата

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;


public class Problem {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<Calendar> dates = new ArrayList<>();

    Calendar dateToChange = Calendar.getInstance();

    System.out.println("При добавлении:");

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

        dateToChange.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 20);
        System.out.println(dateToChange.getTime());
        dates.add(dateToChange);
    }

    System.out.println("При попытке обойти:");

    for(Calendar date: dates) {
        System.out.println(date.getTime());
    }

}

}
```

Comment: Используйте новую библиотеку `java.time`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы добавляете в список ссылку на один и тот же объект `dateToChange`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    Calendar current = dateToChange.clone();
    current.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 20 * (i + 1));
    System.out.println(current.getTime());
    dates.add(current);
}
```